# How to generate a Pcap traffic from Text file with the help of Scapy

Tags: python, wireshark, scapy, pcap

I have multiple text file which I have previously captured via TCPDump, but I didn't set the config correctly and as a result I don't have a complete dump to convert it to pcap file with the help of text2pcap. Therefore, I have tried to write a python script to convert my text files to pcaps.

Following is what my captured file looks like:

```
tcpdump: listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
1509471560.944080 MAC1 > MAC2, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23237, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    IP1.port > IP2.port: Flags [S], cksum 0x6d2f (incorrect -> 0x0b4a), seq 1127096708, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 817985 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
1509471561.042855 MAC2 > MAC1, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 58: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 3107, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 44)
    IP2.port > IP1.port: Flags [S.], cksum 0x85d8 (correct), seq 449984001, ack 1127096709, win 65535, options [mss 1460], length 0
1509471561.044008 MAC1 > MAC2, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 54: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 23238, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    IP1.port > IP2.port: Flags [.], cksum 0x6d1b (incorrect -> 0x9d95), seq 1, ack 1, win 65535, length 0
1509471914.089046 MAC1 > MAC2, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 82: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 54304, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 68)
    IP1.port > IP3.port: [bad udp cksum 0xfe91 -> 0xd1d7!] 10474+ A? 2.android.pool.ntp.org. (40)
1509471914.090059 MAC2 > MAC1, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 520: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 3241, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 506)
    IP3.port > IP1.port: [udp sum ok] 10474 q: A? 2.android.pool.ntp.org. 4/9/11 2.android.pool.ntp.org. A 91.220.110.116, 2.android.pool.ntp.org. A 195.46.37.22, 2.android.pool.ntp.org. A 209.208.79.69, 2.android.pool.ntp.org. A 198.206.133.14 ns: pool.ntp.org. NS c.ntpns.org., pool.ntp.org. NS a.ntpns.org., pool.ntp.org. NS i.ntpns.org., pool.ntp.org. NS g.ntpns.org., pool.ntp.org. NS b.ntpns.org., pool.ntp.org. NS e.ntpns.org., pool.ntp.org. NS f.ntpns.org., pool.ntp.org. NS h.ntpns.org., pool.ntp.org. NS d.ntpns.org. ar: a.ntpns.org. A 207.171.17.42, a.ntpns.org. AAAA 2620:101:d007::42, b.ntpns.org. A 193.243.171.138, b.ntpns.org. A 212.25.19.23, b.ntpns.org. A 174.127.124.192, b.ntpns.org. AAAA 2001:8e0:ffff:1::282, c.ntpns.org. A 199.249.224.53, c.ntpns.org. A 85.214.25.217, c.ntpns.org. A 89.36.18.22, c.ntpns.org. AAAA 2a01:238:426b:900:4535:f84f:5043:4854, c.ntpns.org. AAAA 2a00:14b0:4200:32e0::1e5 (478)
1509471914.090469 MAC1 > MAC2, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 90: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    IP1.port > IP4.port: [bad udp cksum 0xd7a8 -> 0x11f4!] NTPv3, length 48
    Client, Leap indicator:  (0), Stratum 0 (unspecified), poll 0 (1s), precision 0
    Root Delay: 0.000000, Root dispersion: 0.000000, Reference-ID: (unspec)
      Reference Timestamp:  0.000000000
      Originator Timestamp: 0.000000000
      Receive Timestamp:    0.000000000
      Transmit Timestamp:   3718460714.090000003 (2017/10/31 21:15:14)
        Originator - Receive Timestamp:  0.000000000
        Originator - Transmit Timestamp: 3718460714.090000003 (2017/10/31 21:15:14)
```

And Here is the python script in which I have tried to generate a pcap file from my text file using Scapy package:

```
from scapy.all import *
import secrets

def generatePcapfromText(inputtxt,output):
    with open (inputtxt,encoding='cp850') as input:
        framenum=0
        for line in input:
            if "ARP" in line:
                continue
            if line[0].isdigit(): # For Processing the line having Mac address info
                framenum += 1
                frametime=line[:16]
                srcmac= line[18:34]
                dstmac= line[38:54]
               # ethertype = hex(int(line[line.find('(')+1:line.find(')')], 16))
                frameLen=int(line[line.find('length')+7:line.find(': (')])
                frameTos=line[line.find('tos')+4:line.find(', ttl')]
                frameTtl=int(line[line.find('ttl')+4:line.find(', id')])
                frameId=int(line[line.find('id')+3:line.find(', offset')])
                frameOffset=line[line.find('offset')+7:line.find(', flags')]
                frameFlags=line[line.find('[')+1:line.find(']')]
                protocol = line[line.find('proto')+6:line.rfind('(')-1]
                ipLen = int(line[line.rfind('length')+6:line.rfind(')')])

                ether = Ether(dst=dstmac, src=srcmac, type=0x0800)

            elif len(line)>5: # For processing lines having IP addresses info 
                if line[5].isdigit(): # line two
                    srcinfo = line[4:line.find ( '>' )]
                    dstinfo = line[line.find ( '>' ) + 2:line.find ( ':' )]
                    ipsrc = srcinfo[:srcinfo.rfind ( '.' )]
                    ipdst = dstinfo[:dstinfo.rfind ( '.' )]
                    srcport = int(srcinfo[srcinfo.rfind ( '.' ) + 1:])
                    dstport = int(dstinfo[dstinfo.rfind ( '.' ) + 1:])

              ***      ip = ether/IP(src=ipsrc, dst=ipdst, len=frameLen, tos=frameTos, ttl=frameTtl,
                                 id=frameId, flags=frameFlags, proto=protocol.lower())

                    if protocol == "TCP":
                        frameFlag = line[line.find ( '[' ) + 1:line.find ( ']' )]
                        cksum = hex(int(line[line.find ( 'cksum' ) + 6:line.find ( '(' )],16))
                        if ", ack" in line:      
                            seq_n = line[line.find ( ', seq' ) + 6:line.find ( ', ack' )]
                            ack_n = int(line[line.find ( 'ack' ) + 4:line.find ( ', win' )])
                        else:
                            seq_n = line[line.find ( ', seq' ) + 6:line.find ( ', win' )]
                            ack_n = 0

                        if "options" in line:
                            win = int(line[line.find ( 'win' ) + 4:line.find ( ', options' )])
                            options= line[line.find ( 'options' ) + 8:line.find ( ', length' )]
                        else:    
                            win = int(line[line.find ( 'win' ) + 4:line.find ( ', length' )])
                            options="[]"

                        pktlen = int(line[line.find ( ', length' ) + 9:])

                        pkt = ip / TCP(sport=srcport, dport=dstport, flags=frameFlag, seq=seq_n, 
                                       ack=ack_n, chksum=cksum, options=options, window=win) / secrets.token_hex(pktlen)


                    elif protocol == "UDP":
                        if "ok" in line:                            
                            cksum = int(line[line.find ( ']' ) + 2:line.find ( 'q:' )])
                            content = line[line.find ( 'q:' ) + 3:]
                        else:
                            cksum = int(line[line.find ( 'cksum' ) + 6:line.find ( '->' )])
                            content = line[line.find ( ']' ) + 2:]

                        pkt = ip / UDP(sport=srcport, dport=dstport, flags=frameFlag, chksum=cksum) / content

                    wrpcap(output, pkt, append=True)

                elif "Client" in line:
                    continue
                elif "Root" in line:
                    continue
                elif "Originator" in line:
                    continue
                elif "Reference" in line:
                    continue
                elif "Receive" in line:
                    continue
                elif "Transmit" in line:
                    continue
```

However, I get following error. It occurs at the line marked with three stars (***). Moreover, I couldn't find a field to add packet's timestamp, as timestamp is important in my case.

> File "C:\Users\*\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scapy\base_classes.py",
>   line 101, in _parse_net
>       tmp[0] = socket.gethostbyname(tmp[0])
>
> gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

How to solve this error, then?

The problem was with the destination IP which contains the leading space, I have corrected that part of script above. Now, I getting another error. Let see whether I could solve it or I should start another thread.

PS: You can find my original question at [ask.wireshark](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/11741/how-to-convert-tcpdump-output-to-pcap/?comment=11818#post-id-11818).

Comment: You may want to look into why `if line[5].isdigit(): # line two` is never run. Part of that is because you have an elif after `if line[0].isdigit()`. [please edit the code in the question with changes]

Comment: @RossJacobs Without considering those line I'm ignoring them at the end, there are two type of line in my tcpdump: 1- Those start with timestamp which the second if in my script (`if line[0].isdigit()`) aims to process them , 2- Those having some space (Tab) at the beginning having IP addresses, which is the responsibility of the part of code you have mentioned to process. First I make sure that the line length is more than 5 so that I could check whether `if line[5].isdigit()` is true or not. And the error occurs at the body of this if you have mentioned.

Comment: It's good practice (and would be helpful for others reading your code) if you add these kinds of comments to your code. It can be helpful to provide an example ("Matches 012 but not 210"). You probably also want to look into using [Regex](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-regular-expression-tutorial) in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error gives us the information we need:

> tmp[0] = socket.gethostbyname(tmp[0])

Python's `socket` library is trying to do a hostname lookup with [gethostbyname](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.gethostbyname) and it's failing.

For example, this is what usage of this function looks like:

```py
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('google.com')
'172.217.0.46'
```

You may want to try running this on a different computer, because I do not see the same error on my system.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I used this in my script to finding out whether the problem is with source IP or the destination.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `IP(dst=..., src=...)`

If the IPs you pass are invalid, Scapy will try to resolve them with `socket.gethostbyname` (Could it be a domain name?). If those fail, it will raise as so: you are building a packet with something that isn't an IP.

You should check what exactly you are feeding it

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually the IP addresses are valid, as the text file is created via tcpdump. The problem was that the destination address contains the leading space.